# Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeat_vector_40: expected ndim=2, found ndim=1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I am developing an LSTM autoencoder model for anomaly detection. I have my keras model setup as below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras import Model, layers
from keras.layers import Layer, Conv1D, Input, Masking, Dense, RNN, LSTM, Dropout, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Masking, Reshape

def create_RNN_with_attention():
    x=Input(shape=(X_train_dt.shape[1], X_train_dt.shape[2]))
    RNN_layer_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=False)(x)
    attention_layer = attention()(RNN_layer_1)
    dropout_layer_1 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(attention_layer)
    repeat_vector_layer = RepeatVector(n=X_train_dt.shape[1])(dropout_layer_1)
    RNN_layer_2 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True)(repeat_vector_layer)
    dropout_layer_1 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(RNN_layer_2)
    output = TimeDistributed(Dense(X_train_dt.shape[2], trainable=True))(dropout_layer_1)
    model=Model(x,output)
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')    
    return model
```

Notice the attention layer that I added, `attention_layer`. Before adding this, the model compiled perfectly, however after adding this attention_layer - the model is throwing out the following error: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeat_vector_40: expected ndim=2, found ndim=1`

My attention layer is setup as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
class attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(attention,self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name='attention_weight', shape=(input_shape[-1],1), 
                               initializer='random_normal', trainable=True)
        self.b=self.add_weight(name='attention_bias', shape=(input_shape[1],1), 
                               initializer='zeros', trainable=True)        
        super(attention, self).build(input_shape)
 
    def call(self,x):
        # Alignment scores. Pass them through tanh function
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        # Remove dimension of size 1
        e = K.squeeze(e, axis=-1)   
        # Compute the weights
        alpha = K.softmax(e)
        # Reshape to tensorFlow format
        alpha = K.expand_dims(alpha, axis=-1)
        # Compute the context vector
        context = x * alpha
        context = K.sum(context, axis=1)
        return context
```

The idea of the attention mask is to allow the model to focus on more prominent features as is trains.

Why am I getting the error above and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in this line:

```
RNN_layer_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=False)(x)
```

This layer outputs a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 64)`. So this means that you output a vector and then run attention mechanism on w.r.t. to the batch dimension instead of a sequential dimension. This also means that you output with a squeezed batch dimension that is not acceptable for any `keras` layer. This is why the `Repeat` layer raises error as it expects vector of at least shape `(batch_dimension, dim)`.

If you want to run attention mechanism over a sequence then you should switch the line mentioned above to:

```
RNN_layer_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True)(x)
```

Comment: this works now, thanks! I am slightly confused though on how this works and would appreciate a further explanation. So if return_sequences is set to False, the lstm layer will return a tensor of batch dimension instead of sequence dimension? In what cases would I want to return a batch dimension. Also if I was to remove the attention layer, I am still getting a batch dimension (if return_sequences is False) but the model seems to accept that, how is that so? Appreciate further clarity on this!

Comment: In case of a `return_sequences=True` option, LSTM returns tensor of shape `(batch_dimension, sequence_length, data_dim)`. In case of `False` - it return tensor of shape `(batch_dimension, data_dim)` by selecting the output from the last element in the sequence: (output for return_sequences = False) == (output for return_sequences=True)[:, -1, :]

Answer (score 1):

In the shown error, the problem is the mismatch of input dimensions to the `lstm_2' layer. This layer expects the input to be of three dimensions (batch_size, time_steps, features), but your input dimensions (ndim=2) only have two dimensions.

To solve this problem, it must be ensured that the input to this layer is of 3D type. If your model has attention and uses the ``attention'' layer, you must ensure that the output of this layer is correctly specified and matched.

To solve this problem, it is necessary to ensure the correct dimensions for the input to the `lstm_2' layer and, if necessary, make the necessary changes in the model structure.

also, the `RepeatVector` layer is not needed here and should be removed.
beacause, In attention models, ``RepeatVector'' layer is usually not used. This layer helps to repeat the input vector as many times as the output time. But when the attention mechanism is used, there is no need to repeat the output vector because the importance is applied to all times.

More specifically, in your model, the output from the `LSTM'' layer is first taken with` return_sequences=True'' in `RNN_layer_1''. Then, by applying the attention mechanism (through` attention'' layer and `RepeatVector'' to repeat vectors), the importances are determined for each time. Finally, with` TimeDistributed Dense'', the output is calculated for each time.